# count of distinct columns in a record

Tags: sql, oracle

How to count distinct columns  values for a record

```
  C1   C2     C3    C4
  1  USER1  USER2  USER3
  2  USER1  USER1  USER2
  3  USER2  USER3  USER3
  4  USER1  USER1  USER1
```

OUTPUT:

```
 C1   COUNT
  1     3
  2     2 
  3     2
  4     1
```

How to calculate distinct number of users in each record. Is there a way other than comparing column values.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have only 4 columns or you can have more?

Comment: I have 12columns at present, i am expecting logic other than column2<>column3,column2<>column4 comparisons of possible combinations.

Comment: @SiddeshwarGajula Which version of oracle are you using?

Comment: @user75ponic Oracle11g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is with `unpivot`:

```
select c1, count(distinct col) as cnt from (
    select * from your_table
    unpivot( col for lst in(C2, C3, C4) )
) tt
group by c1
```

Answer (score 3):

For only three comparison columns this is the simplest thing which would work:

```
with cte as (
    select c1, c2 from your_table
    union
    select c1, c3 from your_table
    union   
    select c1, c4 from your_table
)
select c1, count(c2) as cnt
from cte
group by c1
/
```

The `union` operator produces a distinct set which feeds into the aggregated count.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
    select c1, c2 from your_table
    union all
    select c1, c3 from your_table
    union all  
    select c1, c4 from your_table
)
select c1, count(c2) as cnt,count(distinct c2) as distinct_cnt
from cte
group by c1
/
```